# How to add marker to map in package:google_maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dart

I didn't know how to add marker to map, because old version I am using jsw.retain([map, marker]);

```dart
 import 'dart:html';
 import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

 void main() {
    final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = new LatLng(43.64825, 142.79392)
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ;
    final map = new GMap(querySelector("#map-canvas"), mapOptions);

   var marker = new Marker(
       new MarkerOptions()
        ..position = new LatLng(43.64825, 142.79392)
        ..map = map
        ..title = 'Foo'
   );

   // How to add marker to map?
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `map` property of the marker with `..map=map` you actually add the Marker to the map. You don't have to do anything else.

You can find an up-to-date example at https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/blob/master/example/04-overlays/marker-simple/page.dart